# Youtube integration in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, ios9, youtube-data-api

I am working on ios app to upload video to youtube. I was searching for any documentation and projects and found a project [here](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS).

When I downloaded the project and tried to run it showing error and the documentation is also not working. I tried creating a project and integrating in to it but after hours of labour I am getting this error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_GTMFetcherApplicationIdentifier", referenced from:
 -[GTLService requestUserAgent] in GTLCommon_Sources.o
"_GTMFetcherCleanedUserAgentString", referenced from:
  -[GTLService setUserAgent:] in GTLCommon_Sources.o
"_GTMFetcherSystemVersionString", referenced from:
  -[GTLService requestUserAgent] in GTLCommon_Sources.o
"_GTMSessionFetcherAssertValidSelector", referenced from:
  -[GTLService
```

I also tried this framework approach but [here](https://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/youtube-api-on-ios/) but still getting error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_YouTubeHelper", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Is there any updated youtube integration method to ios. I have been stuck on it for 2 days. Can anyone point to right direction. I am working on iOS9.

Hope the question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show you code please ? and try to google "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 ios"

Comment: i created a project and trying to follow the tutorial https://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/youtube-api-on-ios/

Comment: The article was written in 2014 I think its not updated

Comment: @Umair Do you know how to implement youtube?

Comment: You read the documentation? and please show some code what you have tried so far.

Comment: @salmancs43 i am running the sample project. There is not much code that I have written. I am trying to compline it and run it on device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985681/how-to-use-youtube-api-for-an-ios-app
may be this link will help you.

Comment: Have you checked issues on Github for that project or tried to create one?

Comment: Have you get the solution of this. I am facing same issue?